# How to define Latitude and Longitude in node.js using google maps package

Tags: node.js, google-maps

How to define Latitude and Longitude in node.js using google maps package?

I tried below code to declare Latitude and Longitude see: var origin1
But it throws gs  has no method 'LatLng'
Can you suggest me to how to define LAtLng??

```
         function calculateDistances() {
              var gs =require('googlemaps');
         //in next line i tried to define LAtLNG it throws gs has no method 'LatLng' 
             **var origin1 = gs.LatLng(13.125511084202,80.029651635576);**
         //Below code i tried in html
         var origin2 = new google.maps.LatLng(12.9898593006481,80.2497744326417);;
        var destinationA = new google.maps.LatLng(13.125511084202,80.029651635576);;
         var destinationB = new google.maps.LatLng(12.9898593006481,80.2497744326417);
     var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
     service.getDistanceMatrix(
      {
     origins: [origin1, origin2],
    destinations: [destinationA, destinationB],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, callback);
  }
```

Comment: I don't see a method called LatLng. Did you refer to the example and documentaion at GitHub? https://github.com/moshen/node-googlemaps

Comment: LatLng is a predefined method of googlemaps.